# Twig Templating Engine for Mobile Devices

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, twig

I'm currently working on a web application and I'm currently using TWIG as my templating engine for my "view" (MVC). I'm just wondering, can we still use Twig if we're going to make a "view" (MVC) of this web app for mobile devices such as android/iphones? If not, what should we use?

Answer (score 1):

The Twig template engine is entirely server-sided. There is not a single reason why it shouldn't work for mobile devices.